# Enable debugging of kernel module from user-space process

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb

I am working with openvswitch on ubuntu 14.04 server. I can easily attach gdb with any of its binary files for debugging its various features but when it comes to its kernel module, I am not able to debug it as per my requirement.
I am using following steps to attach linux kernel with gdb:
1. gdb /tmp/vmlinux /proc/kcore
2. Adding a symbol File to GDB:
    cd /sys/module/openvswitch/sections/
    ls -A1
    .cat .text .data .bss
3. in gdb -  add-symbol-file datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko 0xf87a2000 -s .data 0xf87b4000 -s .bss 0xf87b4560
4. b vxlan_udp_encap_recv

but when I generate packets for testing ovs kernel module and step over it says "The program is not being run."

Note: I have confirmed all module symbols by running this command: nm root/ovs/_build-gcc/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko = which prints all symbols. and lsmod also confirms the existence of ovs kernel module.

I want to make ovs module stop at specified break point after it receives a message from its user-space application on netlink socket for its detailed debugging as conveniently as it allows me to debug a user-space process. Please suggest me how do I resolve this problem or if there is any alternative. I'll be really grateful for any help or suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Imagine if you could set a breakpoint in the kernel, using a debugger on the same machine... then gdb would pause the kernel when the breakpoint is hit, and then your machine would completely freeze because the kernel is paused...

Comment: any resolution of this thread? I met the same issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To debug the kernel you need to use [KGDB / KDB](https://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/).

Comment: I don't have to debug the whole kernel, I just want to debug the behavior of a specific module lying within the kernel.

Comment: @Viciouss: It comes to the same thing, because a kernel module is just a library of code that is loaded and executed within the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility:

run the gdb server on the target machine.  run gdb on another machine. recompile the target machine kernel with the -ggdb parameter on gcc.  start both machines with the target machine running the kernel with all the -ggdb info.  have all the source available on both machines.  connect from the testing machine to the target machine.  have the gdb server connect to the kernel ....